# Second update XSLT using schema-element() to find nodes defined in a schema with no namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm using  XML Editor 18.1 to write and run XSL style-sheet below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">   

<xsl:import-schema schema-location="orig.xsd"/>

<xsl:template match="schema-element(orig)">
...
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`<orig>` is defined as a top level element in the no namespace schema below:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="xml_namespace.xsd"/>


<xs:element name="orig">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            ...
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="pointer_attributes"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

During the stylesheet compilation, Saxon-EE 9.6.0.7 returns the error message below:

> System ID:  Main validation file: ... Engine name: Saxon-EE 9.6.0.7
>   Severity: fatal Description: XPST0008 XSLT Pattern syntax error at
>   char 26 on line 12 in {schema-element(orig)}: There is no
>   declaration for element  in an imported schema Start location:
>   12:26 URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#ERRXPST0008

Compilation is fine with the schema below:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

<xs:element name="orig">
    <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="nested_element" type="xs:string"/>
       </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

However, as soon as I add `vc:minVersion="1.1"` the error is occurring again.

Comment: Are conditions in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-schema-element-test fulfilled? You really should show us minimal but complete samples of XSLT, XSD, we need to see whether the schema has a top level `xsl:element name="orig"`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, yes, `<orig>` is a top-level element (it can be used as a root element for an instance of this schema). I'm trying to debug the XSLT with a simple stylesheet with only the `xsl:import-schema` and the schema-element(orig) template, but Saxon still tell me that `orig` is not declared in the schema.

Comment: As I said, if you want others here to help then it is best to post minimal but complete samples of the code to allow us to reproduce the problem, as you use Saxon you might also want to explain how you try to run the schema-aware transformation exactly (e.g. inside oXygen or from the command line showing the exact command line).

Comment: What namespace declarations are present in the stylesheet? We really need full context to help you debug this.

Comment: I updated the question with my code.

Comment: If that problem occurs with Saxon inside oXygen then you might want to show all your transformation scenario settings and the exact error message. If you run Saxon from the command line then show your command line whether you have validation enabled. You can also use the `-t` option to get exact diagnostics about loaded files.

Comment: I updated my question with Saxon's error message. The error is occuring during the style-sheet compilation.

Comment: Are you configuring Saxon ("set the command line flag -xsdversion:1.1")or Saxon inside oXygen to use the 1.1 schema version?

Comment: See https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/18.0/ug-editor/topics/advanced-saxon-xslt-options.html#advanced-saxon-xslt-options for the oXygen way of setting the schema version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly arising because Saxon is configured to run as an XSD 1.0 processor rather than as an XSD 1.1 processor. The default configuration is XSD 1.0.

You say that you are using XML Editor 18.1 (that's presumably oXygen XML Editor 18.1). So you need to set this configuration parameter within oXygen. In "Configure Transformation Scenario", first select Saxon-EE as the transformer engine; then click on the icon representing "Advanced Configuration Options". Towards the bottom of this form is a section labelled "Saxon-EE specific options", including a radio button to select XSD 1.0 or XSD 1.1.

Comment: Thank you and also thank you to @Martin, Saxon configuration solved the problem.